# Is there a direct connection between the characters' fates and the numbers on the helmets they wear?

Tags: knights-of-sidonia

Numbers frequently have cultural meaning, which can include superstition and foreshadowing. Anime shows, being Asian-derived (Japanese, right), likely have more local meaning. China represents just one example of cultural number meanins (ref: [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numbers_in_Chinese_culture), [chinese.SE](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/826/special-meanings-applied-to-numbers-0-10))

The characters in *Knights of Sidonia* have numbers on their helmets, so I'm wondering if they are at all connected to the fates of the characters wearing them.

From the Wikipedia article the digits "2 and 8" in a number mean "double lucky", while the digit "0" is also lucky and even. Inspection shows that Nagate Tanikaze's helmet contains these three values.

[image: 028]

The digit "6" (in Cantonese) is supposed to mean "to fall" have some unlucky connotations.

[image]

**Question:**

Is there a direct connection between the characters' fates and the numbers on the helmets they wear? Please provide details, clarifications, and references as possible.

Partial list of character names and helmet numbers:

- Nagate Tanikaze, 028 in training, 704 as pilot
- Shizuka Hoshijiro , 336 in training, 702 as pilot
- Izana Shinatose, 291 in training, 723 as pilot
- Yuhata Midorikawa, 256 in training, moves to command.
- Eiko Yamano, 290 as cadet, killed in action
- Hinata Momose, unit designation 002, killed in action
- Kashiwade Aoki, unit designation 003, killed in action
- Izumo Midorikawa, unit designation 004, killed in action
- Ittan Samari, unit designation 005, often acting as field commander
- Koichi Tsuruuchi, unit designation 007, killed in action
- Tonami, unit designation 005, killed in action
- Ichiro Seii, unit designation 026, senior commander
- Do Imada, unit designation 139, killed in action with team (011, 217, and 312)
- En Honoka, 203 as cadet, 703 as pilot, injured in action
- Ho Honoka, unit designation 705, killed in action
- Ren Honoka, unit designation 706, survives.
- Norio Kunato, 001 in training, 701 as pilot, murderer, killed by Ochiai

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for. If you believe that there is some numerology superstition involved, the burden is on you to prove that your theory holds up. So Asians are superstitious about numbers, Japanese are Asians, Knights of Sidonia is a Japanese show. How is this and the numbers pertinent to the series? I don't see any solid connections.

Comment: The market is more than Japan.  The cultures are related, exchange contents and ideas, and have shared lineages.  The ideas of numerology are not unique, and show up in "show business" regularly across the globe.

Comment: I don't think you need to tell a story at the beginning of your question. Can you edit your question so that it doesn't rely on an anecdote?

Comment: @Frosteeze - sure.

Comment: The primary target market for anime is the Japanese. All other audiences are secondary. By making reference to **Chinese** numerology, you don't establish how it is at all related to **Japanese** culture. While one is derived from the other, not all parts of the culture is equivalent. For an example, the number 9 is unlucky in Japanese, pronounced k(y)u, it is a homophone for "suffering/anguish" (苦), but the inverse is true in Chinese, the number 9 is a homophone of the word for "long lasting" (久), and as such is often used in weddings.

Comment: I've made an edit to your question to clarify a connection between the helmets' numbers and the characters. If I changed the meaning of your question, feel free to change it back.

Comment: @ʞɹɐzǝɹ - given the new form of the question, not opinion based, more references, excellent edit by Killua, - can you please take it off of hold?

Comment: @EngrStudent your question notes that the numbers 7 can mean not only "togetherness," but also "ghostly." No where in the two sources you cite is this stated that it also indicates "ghostly." It does cite that in Cantonese that  "it sounds like the verb 'to leave' which adds emphasis." In the future try to make sure that what you're saying matches up with what you cite. Improperly interpreted facts often times lead to misconceptions. It can become quite troublesome on cultural topics due to how varying sensitivity on those topics.

Comment: @ʞɹɐzǝɹ - The SE article has "lucky numbers" but they are followed by "unlucky numbers".  Quote:: 七, the number 7: As stated in the article this number "is considered spiritist or ghostly".

Comment: @EngrStudent the answer cites no specific source for that part. The meaning is not intended to be implied to be in a literally ethereal sense, but a religiously spiritual belief sense of context, and therefore not applicable, unless you can provide a primary or secondary source to corroborate.